# On the intersections between ellipses whose foci are the vertices of any triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, conic-sections, geometric-construction

Given any triangle $\triangle ABC$, we can draw two ellipses, one with foci in $A,B$ and passing by $C$, and one with foci in $C,B$ and passing by $A$. We always obtain the points $D,E$, where these two ellipses intersect.

[image]

What I find nice and interesting (although it is likely an obvious property, sorry in this case!) is that

> **The ellipse with foci in $D,B$ and passing by $A$ pass also by $C$, whereas the one with foci in $E,B$ and passing by $C$ pass also by $A$**,

as illustrated in the following picture.

[image]

To prove this, I tried to use the coordinates, but my calculations are too complicated, and I wonder if there is a more elementary way to show this result.

Thanks for your suggestions, and sorry again if this is too trivial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property can be proved by recalling the ellipse being the locus of points whose sum of the distances to the two focal points is constant.

Since $C$ and $D$ belongs to the ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$ and since $A$ and $D$ belongs to the ellipse with foci $C$ and $B$ we have:
\begin{align}
&\overline{AC}+\overline{CB}=\overline{AD}+\overline{DB}&
&\overline{CA}+\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}+\overline{DB}
\end{align}
Subctrating we get $\overline{DA}-\overline{DC}=\overline{CB}-\overline{AB}$ that's $\overline{DA}+\overline{AB}=\overline{DC}+\overline{CB}$ which implies that $A$ and $C$ belongs to the ellipse with foci $D$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio! That's what I was looking for!